# How to access an union in C

Tags: c, unions

I am confused by using the union, I have tried different ways to access it unsuccessfully. An example:

```
union 
{
    struct 
    {
        char cycle;
        char freq;
        char id;
    } Umember_a;

    char Umember_b[3];
} data_u;

char info[3];
```

I want to copy the "info" array to the union "data_u", but I found there is error if I use any one of the following:

```
memcpy(data_u, info, sizeof(data_u));
memcpy(&data_u, info, sizeof(data_u));
memcpy(data_u.Umember_a, info, sizeof(data_u));
memcpy(data_u.Umember_a, info, sizeof(data_u.Umember_a));
```

but I can use:

```
memcpy(data_u.Umember_b, info, sizeof(data_u.Umember_b));
memcpy(&data_u.Umember_a, info, sizeof(data_u.Umember_a);
```

Could you help to explain this for me?

Comment: What error(s) do you get, for each of those four?

Comment: @Gopi and how's exactly `strcpy()` is better than `memcpy()` here [if not worse] ?

Comment: @Gopi, I wouldn't use `strcpy` here, as it isn't defined the `char` array is zero terminated. `memcpy` or `strncpy` seem a better fit.

Comment: 1) 3) 4) data_u and data_u.Umember_a are not pointers, 2) are you sure about alignment and padding? BTW be aware if you write Umember_a you cannot access data through Umember_b, it's UB...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this approach is doomed to failure since you're assuming that `cycle`, `freq` and `id` are tightly packed in the structure. This is not necessarily the case: the compiler is free to align the structure members in any way it chooses.

You *can* copy `info` to `Umember_b` using a `memcpy`. This will be safe since (i) an array is guaranteed to be contiguous and (ii) the address of `Umember_b[0]` will be the same as the address of `data_u`. But you don't know how that `memcpy` will distribute itself across the elements of `Umember_a`.

Some compilers allow you to change the structure packing but this is simply not portable enough to be reliable.

Comment: Why would the compiler pad members which need no padding? Because it is free to? Pardon my ignorance, but isn't the compiler free to align members when THEY ACTUALLY NEED IT? "Free to align" doesn't really imply arbitrary, random and illogical behavior just for the sake of being free to do it. In this aspect, "doomed to failure" is simply not accurate, it is more like "not guaranteed to work by the standard, but will practically work 99.99999999999999% of the time".

Comment: Also you can easily check that using `offsetof` and simply signify an error if alignment is not as logically expected. Should you spend your life in a deep underground bunker just because a meteorite can hit you at any time?

Comment: @ddriver: Because it may be more efficient to align each field to 32 bits boundaries on architectures that do not support 8 bit reads? That is to say, `sizeof(data_u) == 12` is not unreasonable.

Comment: @MSalters "architectures that do not support 8 bit reads" such as? Also, wouldn't it be more efficient to use shifting and masking for such reads rather than waste 4 times the memory?

Comment: Also, on such a whimsical platform, wouldn't the size of `char[3]` be 12 as well?

Comment: @ddriver: DSP's are the usual suspects. Sure, you _could_ make `char` 32 bits (but `sizeof(char)==1` by definition). That is also reasonable. The idea behind padding fields is that members are typically not accessed sequentially. A `char[3]` usually is accessed sequentially so you can unpack far more efficiently.

Comment: @Bathsheba If so how could I copy a large chunk of data to a structure for safe? Btw I have checked the result and my compiler seems aligned the data as expected.

Comment: Your compiler might. My compiler might eat my cat. You always need to consider packing and alignment when copying data into a structure. Arrays can help in this respect.

Comment: @Bathsheba So can I copy the `info` to `Umember_b` first, and then read back the value by `data_u.Umember_a.cycle`?

Comment: @ddriver Thank you. You taught me a function that I did not know.

Comment: "So can I copy the info to Umember_b first". Yes. That's safe. "read back the value by data_u.Umember_a.cycle" No. That's not safe. Why not ditch `Umember_a` entirely? You could always define cycle to a literal 0 and use `Umember_b[cycle]` etc. In fact, you could refactor to that, post as an answer and I'll certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you cannot do things like `memcpy(data_u, info, sizeof(data_u));`, because memcpy expects a pointer but you pass a variable. This has nothing to do with unions as such. The cases where you pass a pointer to memcpy *should not give errors*. Because in C, any pointer may implicitly be converted to/from a `void*`. If you get an error here, it is because you incorrectly compile your C code as C++, which has stricter type requirements.

`memcpy(&data_u, info, sizeof(data_u));` will work, though strictly speaking this breaks the aliasing rules of C. Particularly because a C struct/union may contain padding bytes. No matter what you plan to do with this union, you need to take padding in account.

`memcpy(data_u.Umember_b, info, 3);` is the most safe and correct way to do this. Whether it will actually work or not depends on if there is padding.